# How to programatically set different values for startRPS and endRPS values for Throughput Shaping Timer in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to find a way to programatically set different startRPS and endRPS for throughput shaping timer like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTf9g.png)

Should mean:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8GiI.png)

Added startRPS and endRPS in UserDefinedVariables and implemented below code in preprocessor:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4xb4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work this way, you need to generate a value showing your desired load pattern for `tst-name.load_profile` property somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) or even beforehand.

See [Special Property Processing](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) chapter of the Throughput Shaping Timer documentation for more details.

Going forward [don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), this way the chance of getting comprehensive help will be much higher.